# Apply interior colour in a With-function to a certain range

Tags: excel, vba

I want to apply an `interior colour` to a list of products in Range `I14:L25`. 
The colour switches between `yellow RGB(255,255,0)` and `gray RGB (217,217,217)` so in the end it should look like this:

---

[image]

---

I tried to go with this `VBA`:

```
Sub Apply_Interior_Colour()

With Sheet1
lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
grey = RGB(217, 217, 217)
yellow = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    
    For i = 1 To lr
    If i = 1 Then
    interior_colour = RGB(217, 217, 217)
    ElseIf .Cells(i, 9).Value <> .Cells(i, 9).Offset(-1, 0).Value Then

        If interior_colour = grey Then
        interior_colour = yellow
        Else
        interior_colour = grey
        End If
        
    End If
        
    .Range(.Cells(i, 9), .Cells(i, 12)).Interior.Color = interior_colour
        
    Next i
        
End With

End Sub
```

---

However, the result looks like this:

[image]

---

What do I need to change in the `VBA` so it looks like in the first screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to

- declaring all your variables, (put `Option Explicit` at the top of your module; also, under `Tools/Options/Editor` select to **require variable declaration** which will do that for any new modules),
- you need to start at the first row of data.
- You may want to clear the formats before you start.
- Since you are processing based on data in column 9, you should be setting your range based on that column and not column 1

eg:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Apply_Interior_Colour()
  Dim lr As Long, fr As Long, i As Long
  Dim grey As Long, yellow As Long, interior_colour As Long

With Sheet1

'You may or may not want/need this line
'Best to restrict to just the area you are coloring
.Cells.ClearFormats

lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row

'You can **find** the first row, or just set it, whatever is appropriate
fr = 14

grey = RGB(217, 217, 217)
yellow = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    
    For i = fr To lr
    If i = fr Then
    interior_colour = RGB(217, 217, 217)
    ElseIf .Cells(i, 9).Value <> .Cells(i, 9).Offset(-1, 0).Value Then

        If interior_colour = grey Then
        interior_colour = yellow
        Else
        interior_colour = grey
        End If
        
    End If
        
    .Range(.Cells(i, 9), .Cells(i, 12)).Interior.Color = interior_colour
        
    Next i
        
End With

End Sub
```

[image]